# How to refresh a table based on api response in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form where i am selecting events from drop down list and selecting a data. Based on date it fetches number of events occured on that date. When i am selecting a event and choosing a date, if events are there it gives list of events in "All Events". But when i change a date on which no events takes place, the "All Events" section does not refresh and gives the previous value coming from api. How to refresh data on html based on api response??

*component.html* code

```
          <form [formGroup]="viewForm" (ngSubmit)="infoSubmit(viewForm.value)">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6 txt-box">
          <select type="number" class="form-control" 
     formControlName="Name">
            <option value="">Events</option>
            <option *ngFor="let Name of listOfEvents"
              type="number" [ngValue]="Name.Id" >
              {{ Name.Name }}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12 txt-box">
          <div class="dateTime row">
            <div class="col-md-3 txt-box">
              <input formControlName="dateStart" [owlDateTime]="dt1"                   
              placeholder="Start Date"/>
              <span [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
              <owl-date-time [showSecondsTimer]="true" #dt1></owl-date-time>
               </div>
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="a-btns btn btn-success tab-btn"  type="submit" >
        Submit
      </button>
           <div class="row">
               <table class="table tabs links">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>All Events</th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let file of AllEventList"> </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
           </form>
```

*component.ts* code

```
      logInfoSubmit(v) {   
   const Id = v.Name;   
if (this.viewForm.valid) {
const dateTime = this.viewForm.value;
let startTimeDate = dateTime.dateStart.toISOString();
const Info = {
  PathDirectory: this.tempLog,
  StartDate: startTimeDate     
};    
this.service.getView(Id,Info).subscribe((res: any) => {
 
  if(res.payload == ''){
   
    this.toastrService.info(res.message);
  }
  else{
    this.AllFileList = res.payload;

    this.toastrService.info(res.message);
  }
  });
 } 
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

The way i see it you are only calling your service to get events once.

Add a (onClick) property to the submit button and call your service again with the new start date.